# How do I list contract to hire on my resume?

Tags: job-search, resume, human-resources, hiring, employment

I was placed through a staffing agency for 4 months at a company. The company ended up hiring me full time after the placement contract expired from the staffing agency. I’ve been with the company around 5 years now!

How do I include the contract to hire portion on my resume?

I don’t want to have another job listed because I was hired for the same exact roles and responsibilities by the company. Also I want to save space.

At the same time I want to be honest and clear and include all of the info.

Comment: I wouldn't bother distinguishing the 4 months and I doubt it would matter to anyone nor that they'd care. ***X years at X Company***.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, in this situation, doesn't really matter who signed your paycheque

If you work in the same team, doing the same work, you can address these 4 months, if ever, as probation period

Comment: I want to know how to list it in my resume really. But it wouldn’t be it’s own position and line. So I do I just notate this beneath the employment dates? “First 4months through staffing agency”

Comment: Don’t bother.  For a formal background check it matters but for a resume, “5 years place x.”

Comment: @AccomplishedHall the point of a resume is to act like a sales brochure to highlight your experience. If you were doing the exact same thing during those 4 months as you were the rest of the 5 years it doesn't need mentioning at all, and it would just add needless complication. You can elaborate during the interview if it becomes at all relevant.

Comment: @mxyzplk so you’re saying just put it on the application but not to note it on the resume? 

Every company would have an application and be running background checks.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m saying.

Answer (score 1):

If they are using the data for a background check or they want you to list all periods of employment without any gaps, then exact company names and dates will be required. You usually see this when they ask you to complete an application or background check form.

If they want exact complete information, then you would treat this as two jobs. You had different employers. You have to be exact because the employment background check will be confirming the dates you were an employee. HR doesn't have any information when you were contracted to do work an contract, they only know when you were an employee.

On the resume you have the ability to be less exact. You could allude to the nature of the first few months by saying it started as a contract-to-hire.

Now if you worked for multiple contracts while working for the staffing company you may have to specifically list the company on the resume if you did work that you want to mention in the resume. You also may have to mention the staffing contract if you are trying to show continuous employment.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me! So would this look appropriate on a resume beneath the official employment dates at the main company as follows:

Primary Company "Start Month. Year - Present" 
"Contract-to-Hire Month. Year - Month. Year via Staffing Agency"?

Comment: @AccomplishedHall, No, the resume doesn't need to include information you put in the job application/background check form.  It's a resume. By definition, it's just summarized information. Do not clutter it up with these details. On your resume, just put your start date and your end date. On the job application itself or the background check form, then you can explain things further. That's the reason why nobody does a background check using a resume. They know that a resume will contain incomplete information.